# In SQL Join 2 tables and get the value for parent records and replace one of the parents dimension value to all its child dimension in sql

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables and am joining them on `tinnumber`, but we group the records based on `PSKUCD` so that we have a family of `tinumber`s under each `pskucd`.  We are joining with `MDM` table because it has updated `brandname`. And `MDM` will have only parent `tinumbers`. I want to use the `mdm` `brandname` from table 2 to update for parent and child `tinumber`'s `brandname` in snapshot table.

Table 1 (snapshot)

```
Pskucd tinnum brandname
234     9999   AMZ
234     10001  AMZt
```

Table 2 (MDM)

```
tinnum bdname
9999    RMZ
```

Desired Output

```
Pskucd tinnum brandname bdname
234     9999   AMZ       RMZ
234     10001  AMZt      RMZ
```

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: SQL Server AzureSQL

Comment: Please correct the tags then.

Comment: select  pskucd,tinnum,[Brand Name],FIRST_VALUE([brand name]) over (partition by pskucd order by tinnum)as Brand from table

Answer (score 0):

One option might be to use outer join with first_value analytic function (sample data from line #1 - 7; query that does the job begins at line #9).

```
SQL> with
  2  snapshot (pskucd, tinnum, brandname) as
  3    (select 234, 9999 , 'AMZ'  from dual union all
  4     select 234, 10001, 'AMZt' from dual
  5    ),
  6  mdm (tinnum, bdname) as
  7    (select 9999, 'RMZ' from dual)
  8  --
  9  select s.pskucd,
 10         s.tinnum,
 11         s.brandname,
 12         first_value(m.bdname) over (order by null) bdname
 13  from snapshot s left join mdm m on m.tinnum = s.tinnum;

    PSKUCD     TINNUM BRANDNAME  BDNAME
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
       234       9999 AMZ        RMZ
       234      10001 AMZt       RMZ

SQL>
```

Comment: Thank you @Littlefoot, i didnt know about this first_value . it really helps the case.